# Joomla logged in user menu

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla-module

I am working on a project in joomla3. It is an event organizer website having frontend (website,template) and back-end (joomla).

Joomla has in built login module. It also has Main Menu and User Menu. The items in Main Menu are :

Home
About US
Events
Gallery
Members
Contact US

The "Members" menu items links to the login module of joomla, so initially, when the user clicks on it, the login form is displayed and the user can login- this is working fine.

What i want to achieve is that all the menu items from Main Menu should be visible to site visitors but when any user logs in, he should see all the Main Menu items and also a "logout" button in the top - along with the menu. This button should be accessible from any page.Something like below :

Home
Home
About US
Events
Gallery
Members
Contact US
LogOut

Currently when i try, i see the login button only on the page on which i include the "login" module (Members Page). I want the user to be able to logout from any page-without clicking on the "members" page again in order to do a logout.

Also once the user is logged in, on the "Members" page, there should be an option for the user to edit his profile. I know there is a "user profile" item available in joomla which allows that but i am not quite getting that worked out.

Can anybody help me on this with the above scenario ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is option to do the same in joomla.
But yes you can achieve this using jquery to append logout form in the existing main menu if the user is logged in.
SO that when the user clicks the logout button he ends up submitting the logout form.